# CodeIgniter blank screen after migration

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have a site written using the CI framework. It worked fine on the original host (Apache). It works fine locally (IIS 7 Express). We have just purchased a new VPS (Windows Server 2008 R2) and php was pre-installed (PHP Version 5.2.10) now when I go to the site I get a blank page.

After debugging by simply printing 'OK' ever so often I determined CodeIgniter.php is failling over on:

```
$CI  = new $class();
```

Now to try and tackle the problem I have gone into config.php and set:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
```

However I am not even getting any log files. I noticed the permissions were not enabled for write so I went to "c:\inetput\wwwroot" and set max permissions for user "IIS_IUSRS"

Unfortunatly still, no log file is created. "index.php" is still blank so I am totally confused. This is my first time working with a CI app. Please help!

Edit: Ensured MySQL Installed and MySQL enabled for PHP

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Make sure php-mysql is installed (with phpinfo()).  I ran into a similar problem and it was all due to php-mysql not being installed.  Not sure how to install it on a windows system, though.

Comment: I think you may be right there. I saw the php mysql library (.dll), but looking closer at phpinfo() I cant see mysql anywhere so its probably just not enabled. I'll take a look and update. I haven't even gotten around to installing the mysql server yet! I wanted to see the "cannot connect to database" error first :-P

Comment: unfortunately even after installing the mysql server and enabling mysql for php and restarting iis (checked and tested) CI still produces a blank page and no logs are created :(

Answer (score 6):

Trevor is right. I had the same exact problem and it was resolved right after installing php-mysql. I am running this on CentOS 6.2 and I did yum install php-mysql and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Had exactly the same problem. In my case, php-mysql was installed yet didn't appear in phpinfo(). I use php-fpm (with nginx) and the reason was that php-fpm needed to be restarted

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as the OP (execution stopped at "$CI = new $class();" in CodeIgniter.php causing a blank page), but I found my answer here: http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-60436.html

Line 257 at system/core/Common.php was

```
return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

I changed it to

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

and the problem went away. It occurred after migrating from PHP 5.4 to 5.6, running CodeIgniter 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an error generated, but not shown due to the default error reporting setting. I usually change the error-reporting setting on my develop machine (in the CI index.php) like this:

```
  if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost") {
    error_reporting(7);
  } else {
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
  }
```

Comment: I have tried this and no error is produced, the code still simply stops at $CI = new $class(); - I guess the error is being suppressed but again I cannot get CI to produce error logs

Answer (score 0):

Change $config['uri_protocol'] to "REQUEST_URI".

Answer (score 0):

**SELF ANSWER:** The cause was white spaces (Had to reformat all the code by opening each file in FTP editor and re-saving)

Comment: could be nice if you explain a little more so others can do it also. where were the white spaces? how did you remove them?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. It was because of the database settings. Check your database settings.

My issue was, I am using expression engine, and the site would go blank at the same line as you have mentioned.
I am using Vagrant, so I had to set the correct port in the database config settings for Expression Engine and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

To turn on errors displaying, change 
`define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');`
 
to 
`define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`

in index.php.

It shows : `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Xml in /www/.../application/libraries/Items/Xml.php on line 3`

Adding ***if*** before class declaration: 
`if (!class_exists('Xml')) { class Xml extends XmlElement {...}` 
solved this problem

Also, work with 
`if (true) { class Xml extends XmlElement {...}`

 Magic! :)

P.S. I'm migrating from php 5.4.36 to 5.6.6-2
I think problem grows from php version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, open config/database.php file and change `'mysql'` to `'mysqli'` in dbdriver.

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```